# migrate a subsite from sharepoint 2013 to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, upgrade, migration, migrate

I want to upgrade sharepoint 2013 on-premise to sharepoint 2016 on-premise 
I have tried Database attach option for 2 weeks but had some problems that couldnt troublshout after all and because we only need one of our subsites to be upgraded in 2016 i decided to look for a another way only to migrate this subsite to our new environment
i have tried backup-spsite from site collection but had some errors related to sql corruption 
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting while doing the content db migration, would you please share here?  By the way for common troubleshooting in content db migration, you may refer the below article :

[SharePoint Migration: Basic tips and tricks in migration project](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/basic-tips-and-tricks-in-sharepoint-migration-project/)

As a second approach, you may use the third party migration tool like sharegate, Metalogix or Microsoft SharePoint migration tool.

Sharegate and Metalogix - trial version is available, you can download it and Microsoft SharePoint Migration tool is a free version, you may use this as well.

Metalogix Download Location :

https://www.quest.com/register/117131/

Sharegate Download Location :

https://sharegate.com/products/sharegate-desktop/trial

Microsoft SharePoint Migration tool Download location :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: i have found database name of my web application and site collections by get-spcontentdatabase next i backed up successfully from sql ms and then restored it

Comment: i have found database name of my web application and site collections by get-spcontentdatabase next i backed up successfully from sql ms and then restored it after  run test-spcontentdatabase against my web app in new environment it appeared some missing assembly and webparts but no upgrade blocking so i mounted and it succesfully finished after that i defined managed path in central admin but when i open my main site collection it says "sorry sth went wrong . an unexpected error has occured" i did troubleshout lots of errors up to reaching this point but i cant find cause of this..

Comment: do you have any link about how to upgrade with metalogix?

Comment: 01/12/2020 18:40:56.16 w3wp.exe (0x5904) 0x0064 SharePoint Foundation General b9y3 High Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Resources\core.fa-IR.resx'. bac72a9f-f7be-50ca-e636-5d85b911b5ee

Comment: above comment is one of high level events in uls logs based on correllation ID

Comment: Added all migration tool download URLs in the answer body

Comment: is microsoft migration tool only for on-premise to online 365 or we can use it for on-premise to on-premise

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one site, I would try [Export-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/export-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps) (or stsadm -o export) to export the site.

Then copy the files to the new server and use [Import-SPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps) (or stsadm -o import).

For individual sites and libraries, I have found it to be more reliable than backup or saving the site as a template with content.

It’s not always as full fidelity as I would like depending on the site though.

To clear the site collection lock:

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://yourSP.com
$site.GetType().GetProperty(“MaintenanceMode”).GetSetMethod($true).Invoke($site,@($false))
```

Comment: i tried to export a subsite(http://intranet/adm/pmo) it exported into 7 .cmp file ...should i import all of them? and should i create new empty site collection in 2016 farm or it will be created automaticlly?

Comment: i tried to import it like this "import-spweb -identity "http://portal:82/adm/pmo" -path c:\pmo-backup\pmo.cmp

Comment: i got this error---->"cannot add content to the site collection because it is locked ..."

Comment: See the end of my edited comment above for the commands to clear the site collection lock.

Comment: And you only import one file. Use the same name you used in the export command.